# Magento 2.1.4 - List of products which have special price with widget conditions

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog, widgets

I try to do a **list of the products** which have a **special price defined**. So I created a widget like that :

[image]

But even the products which have their "Date To" that is passed are shown.

Is it possible to add a condition which **always takes the current date** to filter these products?

Comment: Go to the product and edit special price in advanced pricing option. And check if this help

Comment: I don't want to remove the special price manually. I want that if the end date is passed, the product is not shown in the list. Like that, I still have the previous special price if I want to set it again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't find a fix so a created a PHP script to set to NULL the special prices when their end date is passed.

https://fr.scribd.com/document/346652446/Update-Actions

https://pastebin.com/m1YNTSrs (edit: scribd isn't free, so here's a pastebin)

I call this script with a cron every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I created an extension which lets you list on products on special via a widget

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Special

Plus has controller page

But the widget functionality should be what you need

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Special/blob/ed3ebef80df4f8c2364154d4c94f3a712b5c9c12/Block/Widget/Special.php#L84-L121

```
        $date = new \Zend_Date();

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                'special_from_date',
                [
                    'or' => [
                        0 => [
                            'date' => true,
                            'to' => $date->get('YYYY-MM-dd') . ' 23:59:59'
                        ],
                        1 => [
                            'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
                'left'
            )
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                'special_to_date',
                [
                    'or' => [
                        0 => [
                            'date' => true,
                            'from' => $date->get('YYYY-MM-dd') . ' 00:00:00'
                        ],
                        1 => [
                            'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
                'left'
            )
            ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', ['gt' => '0.1'])
            ->addAttributeToFilter('price', ['gt' => '0.1'])
            ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', ['lt' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('at_price.value')])
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
```